# How to remove single quotes in Struts?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I am passing a Struts property to my JavaScript function as follows:

```
facemode('<s:property value="caseemailnumber" />');
```

I am getting the emailnumber as `'abc@gmail.com'`. I want to remove the single quotes. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that the `caseemailnumber` property itself returned the value with single quotes already and thus your generated JS output ended up invalid as `facemode(''abc@gmail.com'')`? Well, uhm, you could just remove the singlequotes around `<s:property>`, but what are those singlequotes doing in the property value in the first place? Otherwise, I really don't see why they should be removed.

Comment: Yes the single quotes are returned from caseemailnumber.
In firebug i can able to see as facemode(''abc@gmail.com'').So its throwing the errors.
Whether i have to remove the single quotes from the client side or i have to remove it from the server side.

Comment: Those single quotes don't belong in the property value in first place. You need to fix the way how you stored the property in bean or in DB.

Comment: So i have to do by server side.Is there any way to do like    var email=('<s:property value="caseemailnumber" />'); email.replace("'","")

Comment: Yes, but you should not string-replace them. You should **fix** the code which is responsible for inserting single quotes in the property value. You should not *workaround* the problem, you should *solve* the problem at its root cause. Some code in your server is unnecessarily adding those single quotes to the property value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replaceAll` String method and the backslash for the character `'`, like this:

```
facemode('<s:property value="caseemailnumber.replaceAll('\'','')" />');
```

I faced almost the same problem today and it was driving me crazy. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `escapeJavaScript` attribute of the tag:

```
facemode('<s:property value="caseemailnumber" escapeJavaScript="true"/>');
```

However, as BalusC says, it should be stored correctly in the first place--consider scrubbing your data.